# How to pin back the phone tile?

Tags: lumia

I unpinned my phone tile from my start screen on my Nokia Lumia 920, and now I don't know how to put it back.  I can no longer view my call history or dial new numbers, how can I pin it back?

Answer (score 8):

Very simple:

> In the [App list](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ca/how-to/wp8/basics/wheres-the-app-list), tap and hold the app you want to pin, then tap Pin to start.

Source: [Pinning things to Start](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ca/how-to/wp8/start/pin-things-to-start)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Swipe left to all apps, scroll to phone, tap and hold until you can tap pin to start.